# Android: Loading Multiple Images from Multiple Sources, Slow

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask

So I am trying to load about 25 images at once using the AsyncTask class.

In short I'm calling this inside the AsyncTask to download the image from the server:

```
Url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
urlConnection.disconnect();
```

As you can see in this video, it results in poor performance. Presumably because it is loading the images one at a time as the AsyncTask queues each of them up, I think?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dqVqLn5Ibs

So the solution would be to load them all asynchronously, but I dont know how I would achieve this without needed a whole lot of new code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).
It loads each image in separate thread.It is very easy to use and takes care of most of the things like caching..etc.

Ex usage:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView);
```